# Add custom component tag in alert Ionic 4

Tags: angular, components, alert, logout, ionic4

I'm working with ionic 4.9.0. I want to add my component tag in alert. But it is not working.

Here's my alert code.

```
async navigateTo(url)
  {
    let logoutAlert;
    if(url != 'logout')
      this.router.navigate(['/menu/' + url]);
    else
    {
      logoutAlert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        message: "<logout></logout>"
      });
      await logoutAlert.present();
    }
  }
```

Here's my logout.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'logout',
  templateUrl: './logout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logout.component.scss']
})
export class LogoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logout()
  {
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');
  }
}
```

Here's my logout.component.html file

```
<div>Are You sure?
  <button (click) = "logout()">Yes</button>
  <button>No</button>
</div>
```

Other suggestions will be appreciated too. Thanks.

Comment: What is not working? Does the alert not show? Or can't you see / press the buttons in the alert?

Comment: Plus: why don't you use buttons directly in the alert? (as shown in the docs: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert)

Comment: I know it's late, but for anyone still looking for this I added a link to a package I created to handle this to this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132453/passing-html-template-and-icons-on-alert-ionic-4

Answer (score 0):

Ionic alerts can't use custom components. In `message`, you can only pass `string` with basic/core HTML tags (like `strong`, `h1`, `p`, etc.), but not custom components. And alerts are designed for that purpose only, to provide minimum and important information.

If you really want to use the custom component in the alert, you can use [modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal/) and design them as an alert.

Comment: ...Thanks. But modal is a full page. And I only need a dialog.

Comment: You can stylize modal, see this : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-modal-alert-with-html-form/47980/4

Comment: @shhdharmen that's v3,I cant't make it work on v4 since I cannot dismiss the dark background