# passing html template and icons on alert ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image: sample of the target]

I have been trying to achieve something like the above in ionic 4 but it seems like there is no hope for me cos it seems I can only use inputs and not a custom HTML & icons been passed on the alert. any idea on how to achieve this pls

```js
async presentColor() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: "Choose Color",
      inputs: [
        {
          name: "Red",
          type: "checkbox",
          label: "Red",
          value: "Red",
          checked: true
        },

        {
          name: "Black",
          type: "checkbox",
          label: "Black",
          value: "Black"
        },
        {
          name: "purple",
          type: "checkbox",
          label: "Purple",
          value: "Purple"
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          role: "cancel",
          cssClass: "secondary",
          handler: (data) => {
            console.log("Confirm Cancel", data);
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Ok",
          handler: () => {
            console.log("Confirm Ok");
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: I'd recommend using an ionic modal component and trim it to be the size of an alert dialog. This way you can include whatever html template and icons you desire.

Comment: does it mean i can't achieve it with alert? or it's a bad idea @Jay

Comment: I left a response as an answer, in general the ionic team provides a lot of components as basic templates and as users we can build upon them, so in this case and many others, they try not make the default components too customizable by default. I'd suggest making a custom modal alert component.

Answer (score 1):

The Ionic team has not made alert components easily customizable so icons can be added to the alert component. See issue:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7874

But you could easily create a modal component and reduce its size to be closer to that of the alert dialog box.

Comment: Thanks@Jay... I have tried using the modal but I have another challenge. the backdrop of the modal is not coming even though I have played with the **showBackdrop:false** option since the modal by default is a full page... any idea of how to go about this??

Answer (score 0):

Why you want use ion alert.
You can use other components like 
[popovers](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#popovers) to do that

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but I just created an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-custom-alert) to handle adding an angular component into a popup.